# Copying large files between servers corrupts data in them

Tags: linux, xml, server, scp

I've in a Centos 7 server (let's call it server_A) 8 files like this one. All of them with a size a little less than 3G:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr grp 2,7G jan 31 21:09 FilePart1.xml
```

They are automatically created once a week and then I move them, also automatically, to another server using cron:

```
0 4 * * 1 scp -oPort=XXX /<<directory>>/FilePart* remote_usr@Server_B:/<<remote_dir>>/
```

The copy works fine **BUT**, there is always some parts that during the copy process they get corrupted. The size is correct but when I run xmllint I have:

- Server_A:

  -rw-r--r-- 1 usr grp 2893589079 ene 31 21:09 FilePart1.xml 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 usr grp 2964663502 ene 31 21:19 FilePart2.xml 
  ...
  XMLLINT:
  <>
- Server_B

  -rwxr-xr-x 1 usr grp 2893589079 feb  1 04:09 FilePart1.xml 
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 usr grp 2964663502 feb  1 04:15 FilePart2.xml 
  ...
  XMLLINT:
  /dir/FilePart1.xml:2807901: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: datafield line 2807901 and subfield 
  /dir/FilePart1.xml:2807903: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: record line 2807888 and datafield 
  /dir/FilePart1.xml:2807930: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: collection line 1 and record 
  /dir/FilePart1.xml:2807931: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

Where's the problem? The 'scp' process over networks? How could I trace it? To patch it, I could gz the files and send them....but I think is not the 'solution'.

Any help would be mush appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it is the copy that does it? What does `sum` say?  What happens when you stop the applications on both servers before doing the copy? What happens when you copy using a USB drive? Is the version of xmllint and the environment the same on both servers?

Comment: What is actually wrong with the files? For example, what is the extra content at the end of the file?